# Como inverter datas no PHP, independente do formato?

Tags: php, data, formatação

Como inverter datas no PHP? Preciso inverter datas no PHP independente do formato de entrada, seja `YYYY-mm-dd` ou `dd/mm/YYYYY`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Versão com [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php):

```
function inverteData($data){
    if(count(explode("/",$data)) > 1){
        return implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));
    }elseif(count(explode("-",$data)) > 1){
        return implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$data)));
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
$data = "1992-10-01"; //ou 01/10/1992
echo inverteData($data);
```

---

> **Obs.: Lembrando que esta solução funciona corretamente apenas com as entradas `dd/mm/YYYY` ou `YYYY-mm-dd`, alternando o resultado entre os dois formatos.**

Comment: ótima solução para o problema!

Comment: -1 Por assumir que irá receber uma entrada esperada sem validar se ela é de fato o que se espera.

Comment: @Bacco pelo que eu entendi da pergunta dele, *"independente do formato de entrada"* seria relativo à *"`YYYY-mm-dd` ou `dd/mm/YYYYY`"* e não a todos os tipos de data [suportados](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) pela linguagem.

Comment: @Kazzkiq até entendi isso, o que eu acho complicado é que na maior parte das respostas, não apenas na sua, não está claro o que é dia e o que é mês (mas concordo que a pergunta está com problemas, e não a resposta em si)

Comment: Concordo que o ideal seria uma solução que aceitasse qualquer formato e que convertesse para qualquer formato que o usuário definisse. Mas a pergunta em sí é superficial e abrange apenas 2 casos. Não sei nesses casos o melhor é responder pensando só na pergunta, ou em uma solução 100% completa.

Comment: O mais interessante é que ele não afirmou que quer inverter de um formato pra outro e vice versa, daria pra interpretar de mil maneiras. O accept é sinal de que você fez o que ele queria (ou, no pior caso, que ele não testou ambas as condições). Realmente só o @FlavianoSilva comentando mesmo pra entendermos o que ele gostou e o que não gostou em cada caso :)

Comment: Para o meu caso também foi perfeito, obrigado @Kazzkiq

Answer (score 19):

Ao invés de usar funções maiores, você pode seguir por 2 caminhos mais "rápidos" ou "melhores" ao meu olhar.

Caso você esteja usando algum banco SQL e queira que ele retorne a data já formatada você pode utilizar:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tbl_data,'%d/%m/%Y') as data FROM tb_tabela
```

Caso queira fazer a conversão no PHP mesmo, utilize :

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime($ln['data_cadastro']));
```

Answer (score 11):

Baseado no que foi descrito...

```
function swap_date($date_str)
{
    if ($date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date_str)) {
        return $date->format('d/m/Y');
    } elseif ($date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_str)) {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid input date format.');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Uma solução deveras elegante na minha opinião, criada por um colega de fórum gira em torno [da solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21795/250) proposta pelo Harry Potter logo acima (ou abaixo :p):

```
/**
 * Altera uma data para outro formato
 * 
 * @param string $date String contendo a data a ser formatada
 * @param string $outputFormat Formato de saida
 * @throws Exception Quando não puder converter a data
 * @return string Data formatada
 * @author Hugo Ferreira da Silva
 */
function parseDate($date, $outputFormat = 'd/m/Y'){
    $formats = array(
        'd/m/Y',
        'd/m/Y H',
        'd/m/Y H:i',
        'd/m/Y H:i:s',
        'Y-m-d',
        'Y-m-d H',
        'Y-m-d H:i',
        'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    );

    foreach($formats as $format){
        $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        if($dateObj !== false){
            break;
        }
    }

    if($dateObj === false){
        throw new Exception('Invalid date:' . $date);
    }

    return $dateObj->format($outputFormat);
}
```

Nela podemos informar a data em qualquer formato de entrada e um formato de saída. Contanto que o formato seja suportado pela classe [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime):

```
$testDates = array(
    '2012-10-30 00:00:00',
    '06/01/1986 14',
    '06/12/1983 14:30:10',
    '1984-01-06 14:30:10',
);

foreach($testDates as $date){
    echo parseDate($date, 'd/m/Y H:i:s'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Demo no [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d7b524ad43273f65923cbb0988048e8beb00571)

---

A solução [atualmente marcada como melhor resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21790/250), desculpa a franqueza, sofre de um problema conceitual sério descrito no paradigma do DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) que não é algo unicamente voltado à orientação a Objetos.

Na solução apresentada toda a lógica poderia ser reaproveitada por utilizar parametrização. Parece complicado por causa do palavrão (:p), mas é simples, bastaria adicionar um outro parâmetro com o separador a ser utilizado:

```
function invertDate( $date, $separator ) {
    return implode( $separator, array_reverse( explode( $separator, $date ) ) );
}
```

E tudo é resolvido numa única linha.

Há quem diga que essa simplificação é prejudicial pois apesar de inverter a data mantém o separador de entrada.

Para esses, posso fazer duas considerações:

1. Se a Aplicação precisar normalizar um dado de entrada, teoricamente ela deve armazenar o dado normalizado num único formato. Nesse caso, bastaria trocar a primeira ocorrência de **$separator** por uma string fixa:

   ```
   function invertDate( $date, $separator ) {
       return implode( '/', array_reverse( explode( $separator, $date ) ) );
   }
   ```
2. Se o dado de entrada aceitar vários formatos de entrada, a Aplicação tem sérios problemas de modelagem e/ou carece de validação de dados.

Mas ainda assim é possível melhorar para não haver repetição. Uma de muitas possibilidades seria, depois de remover as letras do dado de entrada, contar a quantidade de caracteres não numéricos da string e usá-lo como separador. [Aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50cc67e9d98422a0a0b102bf91347888193c0436), um código grosseiro que demonstra a idéia.

A idéia é analisar a string ver qual caractere não (alfa-)numérico mais se repete e usá-lo como separador.

> O código do link acima **não foi** otimizado onde possível por não se tratar MESMO da melhor alternativa.

Comment: Essa é uma excelente resposta, parabéns ...

Comment: Pelo visto não é a opinião de dois cidadãos que preferiram negativar sem motivo claro. Tsc...tsc...

Comment: A resposta enfatizou mais a função `invertDate()`, suscetível aos mesmos problemas da resposta original, do que a `parseDate()`, de fato elegante e, mais que isso, adequada para trabalhar com datas. Como a resposta ficou longa, se analisada de forma prematura, acaba deixando a desejar... Mesmo que uma aplicação faça validação de seus dados antes de usar uma função como esta, não há como assumir que a função realmente irá receber os argumentos da maneira esperada.

Comment: É, olhando por esse ângulo, matar dois coelhos com uma cajadada só pode não ter sido mesmo a melhor saída. Vou colocar pelo menos um separador pra ficar mais evidente.

Comment: Inverter a resposta, colocando a solução elegante em evidência, e comentando a solução marcada como melhor resposta depois, certamente agregaria mais à resposta. Isso porque, não importa de onde venha o dado ou se ele foi alterado antes de passar pela função `parseDate()`, ao contrário da `invertDate()`, ela não falhará a ponto de gerar um erro dentro dela. :)

Comment: Verdade, não havia pensado nisso na hora. Vou inverter.

Answer (score 4):

```
function InvertData($campo){

    if(substr($campo,2,1)=='/'){
        $campo=substr($campo,6,4).'-'.substr($campo,3,2).'-'.substr($campo,0,2);//2012-10-10
    } else {
        $campo=substr($campo,8,2).'/'.substr($campo,5,2).'/'.substr($campo,0,4); //10/10/2012
    }

    return($campo);

}
```

Comment: Esta função inverte datas de formato dd/mm/aaaa para YYYY-mm-dd e de YYYY-mm-dd para dd/mm/aaaa.

Comment: -1 Por assumir que irá receber uma entrada esperada sem validar se ela é de fato o que se espera.