# Inserir data no MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Quero inserir de um FORM em HTML que fiz o campo `DATE`, contudo ele esta no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` e o mysql aceita somente `yyyy-mm-dd`. Como faço para converter a data para inserir corretamente no banco de dados MySQL usando o PHP?

Tentei achar em vários lugares e nada que me ajudasse, pois a data salva no BD sempre é uma nada haver com a digitada quando vou verificar.

Atualmente meu codigo tem o campo `DATA` neste formato:

```
$dataOld=date("d/m/Y");
$data=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dataOld));

$venc_garantiaOld=date("d/m/Y");
$venc_garantia=date("Y/m/d", strtotime($venc_garantiaOld));
```

PS: não sei se interfere na conversão, mas estou usando no form uma mascará em jQuery para o campo `DATE`, será que tem problema?

Comment: Outras opções, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21774/como-inverter-datas-no-php-independente-do-formato

Comment: Tentei a função que se encontra no link, mas não funcionou comigo.Tem outra sugestão? no Mysql mesmo com a função ele salva com a data do sistema no BD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consegui graças ao pessoal do hardware: http://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/data-duvida/902709/

Para quem tiver a mesma duvida que tive a implementação que usei foi da seguinte forma:

```
`$data = $_POST['data'];
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data));

$data = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data)));  
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data));


$venc_garantia = $_POST['venc_garantia'];
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($venc_garantia));

$venc_garantia = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$venc_garantia))); 
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($venc_garantia));`
```

Os ECHO são apenas para imprimir o valor na pagina para ver as datas como estão saindo, mas isso me garante inserir com sucesso no mysql sem problemas. Contudo agradeço a ajuda e auxilio de todos!

Answer (score 2):

Após receber o campo data do seu form, você terá que inverta a data, abaixo segue uma sugestão:

```
implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $data)))
```

Comment: como eu insiro isso? coloco `$data = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $data)));` seria assim?

Comment: você pode usar desta forma que mencionou @DarkJontex!

Comment: ja tentei e nao funciona. Ele salva no Mysql com a data do sistema. :/ não sei o que faço, eu fiz assim:

    `$venc_garantia=date("d/m/Y");
    
    $venc_garantia = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$venc_garantia)));

    $data=date("d/m/Y");    

    $data = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));`

Comment: @DarkJontex, como assim com a data do sistema? Você está passando a data do sistema quando faz isso: "date("d/m/Y")"..

Comment: é assim, eu recebo do <form> que é um formulario de cadastro um equipamento. Nele eu recebo no formato (dd-mm-YYYY), e depois uso sua função. Isto é para Data e para Garantia. Com tudo isso eu fiz esse script que passei e não resolveu meu problema :/ o que me sugere? Quero apenas salvar do PHP que esta no formato dd-mm-YYYY para o formato do mysql que é YYYY-mm-dd

Comment: Se você está recebendo a data no formato: dd-mm-YYYY, você terá que alterar a função que lhe passei. Faça a seguinte mudança, de: explode('/', $data) para: explode('-', $data). Veja se funciona!

Comment: conseguiu @DarkJontex?

Comment: Não Weliton Junior. De fato foi o seguinte me expressei errado, mas não funcionou de todo modo: minha data salva é do tipo dd/mm/YYYY (pela mascara Jquery). Em seguida quero o php salve essa data no mysql no formato YYYY-MM-DD. Contudo mesmo usando essa forma e a original, eu não obtive sucesso. Será por causa que quem faz a mascara é o Jquery? como faço uma mascara de data no PHP para os campos em HTML?

Comment: Meu código atual esta assim:
    `$venc_garantia=date("d/m/Y");
    $venc_garantia = implode("-",array_reverse(explode('/',     $venc_garantia)));

    $data=date("d/m/Y");
    $data = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));`

Answer (score 1):

@DarkJontex, o que eu sempre faço e que é muito simples, é o seguinte:

```
//Pegue a data no formato dd/mm/yyyy
$data = $_POST['dataDoCampoHTML'];
//Exploda a data para entrar no formato aceito pelo DB.
$dataP = explode('/', $data);
$dataNoFormatoParaOBranco = $dataP[2].'-'.$dataP[1].'-'.$dataP[0];

//Na hora de pegar a data do BD e exibir na tela, faça a mesma coisa que fiz acima, porém troquei '-' por '/':
$data = $row['dataDoBanco'];
$dataP = explode('-', $data);
$dataParaExibir = $dataP[2].'/'.$dataP[1].'/'.$dataP[0];
```

OBS: Antes de dar um explode, de um echo em na variável que recebe a data vinda do campo:

```
$data = $_POST['dataDoCampo'];
echo $data.'<br>';
```

Para ver se a data está no formato dd/mm/yyyy ou yyyy-mm-dd, certo?
Sempre fiz assim e sempre deu certo.