# Como salvar data fornecida pelo usuário no MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

Tenho um *form* que possui um campo onde é inserido a data de nascimento do usuário, este campo possui um `datepicker` que já retorna a data no formato ano,mês,dia, esta data é acessada através de `$_GET['birthdate']` seu formato é *string*, então meu questionamento é como inseri-la no banco de dados? Tenho que atribuir esta data a um objeto intermediário?

Comment: Acho que isto foi respondido provavelmente de várias formas diferentes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26968/101 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40262/101 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40731/101 http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+formato+data

Comment: Olá bigown, verifiquei os links o que mais me preocupa é o formato da data que possui este formato: 1980/01/13, qual modificação deveria ser feita para inseri-la no mysql e como faria

Comment: Este é um dos formatos aceitos pelo MySQL, você está tendo algum problema? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: devo mudar para algum tipo especial do php ou posso inserir direto na forma string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seria assim:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['birthdate'])); //converte para tipo date
mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO tabela (birthday) VALUES ($date)");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/co04xQ)<sup>na medida do possível</sup>. E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/SaveDate). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/SaveDate.php).

[Documentação do MySQL sobre datas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

[Documentação do `strtotime()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

[Documentação do `date()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Note que a *string* com data precisa estar em um formato minimamente reconhecível pelo PHP. Caso contrário ou falhará ou precisará fazer um *parse* mais completo para identificá-la.

Comment: Era esta modificação que procurava

Comment: É sempre bom checar o que o usuário está enviando, antes de salvar no banco. Sugiro uma olhada nas respostas [desta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773418/regex-to-validate-date-in-php-using-format-as-yyyy-mm-dd) pergunta.