# inserir data no banco mysql "ex. dia/mês/ano"

Tags: php, mysql

Sou iniciante, utilizo o bd mysql e o php, estou com dúvida referente ao meu insert no banco.

uso o seguinte input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Data de início" class="btntarefa" name="dataInicio" id="dataInicio" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'DD.MM.YYYY'}">
```

após executar meu insert:

```
$comandoSql="INSERT INTO tbTarefa 
                         (nomeTarefa, dataInicio , dataTermino, anexos, observacao, status, codObra)    
                    VALUES 
                         ('".$tarefa."', '".$data1."', '".$data2."', '".$anexo."', '".$observacao."', '".$status."', '".$idObra."')";
```

o resultado é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é como eu posso inserir no formato de dia/mês/ano

eu pesquisei e encontrei isso:

SET evn_dtevento = STR_TO_DATE( "31/05/2014", "%m/%d/%Y" )

Porém tentei adapta-lo em meu insert e apresentou erro de sintaxe, poderiam me ajudar referente isso ou outra maneira que possa resolver meu problema, desde já Obrigado

Comment: ja tentou isso > **data-uk-datepicker="{format:'YYYY.DD.MM'}"** muita das vezes funciona!

Comment: O Banco de dados MySQL é configurado `ANO/MES/DIA` é o seu padrão de armazenamento de datas. Quando você receber a data, deve converter nesse formato e gravar na base de dados como já disse.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26968/inserir-data-no-mysql-via-php

Comment: Aqui várias formas de conversão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21774/como-inverter-datas-no-php-independente-do-formato

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod Obrigado, após verificar o link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26968/inserir-data-no-mysql-via-php, eu encontrei isso 

echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($venc_garantia)); 

e assim resolvi armazenar em uma variavel e depois exibi-la segue: 

$dInicio = $linha['dataInicio'];
$dInicio1 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dInicio));