# Data no formato dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: php, mysql

eu criei uma tabela, onde coloco o registro do usuario num cartão para impressão; portanto esta tabela tem varios registros(5 por pag) e para que em cada pagina eu acesse um registro na mesma tabela fiz um array_push com os valores -->

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartao LIMIT $inicial, $numreg ");
$sql_conta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartao ");
$quantreg = mysql_num_rows($sql_conta); 

$Nascimento = array();
$Batismo = array();
$Comunhao = array();
$Emissao = array();

while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql_conta, MYSQL_ASSOC)){;
  array_push($Nascimento, $linha['Nascimento']);
  array_push($Batismo, $linha['Batismo']);
  array_push($Comunhao, $linha['Comunhao']);
  array_push($Emissao, $linha['Emissao']);

}if ($_GET['pag'] > 0 ){  
$pegaid = (int) $_GET['pag'];
$id = "$pegaid";
$soma = $id * 5 ;
}
```

Dentro da Tabela puxo os dados do registro que saem em formato ('yyyy/mm/dd') 
a tabela funciona assim:

```
td height="42"><a>Nascimento:</a>
                   <?php
                  echo '<b>'; 
                 if ($_GET['pag'] > 0 ){
                     print $Nascimento[0 + $soma]; 
                 }else{
                     print $Nascimento[0];
                     }
                 echo '</b>';    
                     ?>
                  </td>
```

Queria SABER como inverter o formato sem dar problema no resto do codigo os outros registros tirei por achar sem importancia.
 OBS:. Todos os registros ai são datas; O registro emissão é um registro automatico!!! Alguemme ajuda.

Comment: [Pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21774/como-inverter-datas-no-php-independente-do-formato)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Otimizando o contador da sua consulta:
<sub>Sua query não conta, ela retorna TODOS os registros!!!</sub>
`SELECT * FROM cartao`
<sub>O correto seria:</sub>
`SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM cartao LIMIT $inicial, $numreg`

Minha sugestão para contar os registros fica abaixo:

<sub>**1ª QUERY:** `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM cartao LIMIT $inicial, $numreg`</sub>
<sub>**2ª QUERY:** `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`</sub>
`FOUND_ROWS` vai retornar o total de registros

---

<sub>**1)** usando a classe `DateTime`</sub>

```
$date = new DateTime( '2014-08-19' );
echo $date-> format( 'd-m-Y' );
```

<sub>**2)** Como na referencia postada pelo @Kazzkiq</sub>

```
date( 'd-m-Y' , strtotime( '2014-08-19' ) );
```

---

<sub>Os 2 modos produzem o mesmo resultado:</sub>

<sub>**input**: 2014-08-19</sub>
<sub>**output**: 19-08-2014</sub>

Comment: Amigo a sua resposta foi a unica que deu certo no meu caso então Vlw

Comment: Blz. Só 1 pergunta, qual o proposito de `$sql_conta`? Acho que sua consulta pode ser otimizada...

Comment: SQl_Conta puxar os dados da tabela já o SQl é fazer a paginação; a intenção da pagina e criar varios cartoes para impressão

Comment: Sim só mais uma pergunta caso a pessoa tiver nascido antes de 1970 como faço para por a data ??? usei o caso 2

Comment: Atualizei sua query para o contador de registros. Qual a dúvida com relação ao nascimento anterior a 1970?

Comment: Nada mais vlw a atenção amigo já resolvi!!! eu pensei que se houvesse uma data anterior a 1970  daria erro; mais deixa que eu esqueci de por o nascimento no BD

Comment: **1)** Para comparar uma data DMY você pode usar `if( strtotime( '1969-06-24' ) <= strtotime( '1970-06-24' ) ) // anterior`. **2)** sua `$sql_conta` está muito errada, seu contador retorna dados enquanto deveria retornar apenas o total (count(*) as count)

Comment: Vc pode explicar melhor O contexto da $sql_conta
OBS:. A sql_conta pega mais dados alem de datas pega endereço de imagem e text

Comment: sua 1ª sql deve retornar os dados que você necessita e a segunda deve ser o contador

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16549/discussion-between-papa-charlie-and-eder).

Answer (score 2):

Na própria SQL você utilize [date_format](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) igual exemplo logo abaixo:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT date_format(Nascimento,'%d/%m/%Y') Nascimento, Batismo, Comunhao, Emissao FROM cartao LIMIT $inicial, $numreg ");
$sql_conta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartao ");
$quantreg = mysql_num_rows($sql_conta); 

$Nascimento = array();
$Batismo = array();
$Comunhao = array();
$Emissao = array();

while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql_conta, MYSQL_ASSOC)){;
     array_push($Nascimento, $linha['Nascimento']);
     array_push($Batismo, $linha['Batismo']);
     array_push($Comunhao, $linha['Comunhao']);
     array_push($Emissao, $linha['Emissao']);

}
if ($_GET['pag'] > 0 ){  
    $pegaid = (int) $_GET['pag'];
    $id = "$pegaid";
    $soma = $id * 5 ;
}
```

Comment: Usar o SQL para formatar uma saida não é a melhor opção. Imagina o seu sistema multi-idioma, você vai precisar formatar a QUERY para uma data em cada idioma, ou resolve mudar de `10/06/2014` para `10 de Junho de 2014`... Nada prático

Comment: @PapaCharlie discordo, depende muito do contexto e do volume de dados.

Comment: @gmsantos, respeito mas também discordo :) É uma questão de lógica. Se usar o SQL para formatar a data em um formato específico terá uma aplicação muito engessada, se quiser alterar o formato inevitavelmente terá que mudar a QUERY. Pior será se ele quiser implementar um sistema de cache, neste caso nem QUERY será executada...

Comment: Estas focando em um contexto específico.    Pegue um banco com um milhão de colunas e imprima todas no php. Formatar diretamente a query é bem mais rapido que iterar linha a linha no php para alterar o formato

Comment: Eu estou focando em um Contexto específico??? Citei 3 casos distintos e completamente usuais... Você que focou em volume de trafego...

Comment: @Maria eu não sei o que fiz de errado segundo sua resposta, seu eu coloca-se date_format invertia, mais aqui esta dando erro!!! Não funciona, já tentei no $sql e $sql_conta e nada alguem pode me ajudar devido ao array_push não funciona

Comment: @PapaCharlie só esteja ciente em não sobrecarregar camadas de sua aplicação: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168/why-are-relational-set-based-queries-better-than-cursors

Comment: Se você executa uma consulta para ter uma data `D-M-Y` e depois precisa formatar para `Y-M-D` ou `D-M-Y` de acordo com a escolha do usuário, pode me dizer diga qual seria sua sugestão?

Comment: Sobre os comments acima: creio que para internacionalizar, bastaria localizar o %d/%m/%Y na hora de enviar a query, em vez de fazer no output. Quanto ao erro mencionado pelo OP, acho que é apenas um probleminha de sintaxe na query da resposta.

Comment: O mais comum é fazer na SQL e não acredito ter nenhum problema visto que o seu código para internalização dita por ti também deverá passar por mudanças, sinceramente não claro @PapaCharlie, posso respeitar sua posição, mas eu discordo de você por causa disso.

Comment: @Eder em qual linha está dando problemas, talvez possa te ajudar ?

Comment: No meu exemplo basta alterar a `view` e compor o `HTML` no formato que quiser sem passar por nenhuma mudança. Todos respeitamos e discordamos e o resultado é um debate produtivo :)

Comment: @Bacco, exatamente isso, na melhor das hipótese vai ter que buscar parametros. `SELECT date_format(field , $formato_pt | $formato_en )`... Agora aplice isso em um sistema de cache que não use DB, um TXT ou XML... Olha o gesso

Comment: @PapaCharlie você está complicando um assunto que está definido, ele quer em formato brasileiro está descrito na pergunta (Data no formato `dd/mm/yyyy`), desculpa parece besteira mas, o que vai fazer fica na mesma diante do seu código...

Comment: Não estou complicando, apenas dei uma resposta que possibilite o sistema funcionar em qualquer situação, inclusive trabalhando com dados que não sejam do SQL... até

Comment: @PapaCharlie essa afirmação sua só é verdade com paramentros o mesmo modo que posso trabalhar com a minha resposta na SQL, até.

Answer (score 2):

Usando um simples [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) e [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php):

```
$date = '2014-08-19';
echo implode('/',array_reverse(explode('-',$date)));
```

Comment: -1 Essa maneira não é muito apropriada. Creio que é mais legível utilizar o `Datetime`.