# Validar diferentes formatos de data

Tags: php, data

Estou com dificuldade para validar diferentes formatos de data. Preciso converter as datas para o formato `Y-m-d` para salvar no banco.

As datas vêm assim:

```
11/12/2014 // MÊS/DIA/ANO
30/10/2014 // DIA/MÊS/ANO
```

Já tentei da forma simples:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('11/12/2014')); // 2014-11-12 = OK
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('31/10/2014')); // 1970-01-01 = FAIL
```

Comment: Outras formas de converter: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21774/91

Comment: Infelizmente é impossível determinar com exatidão que tipo de data você esta recebendo quando elas forem ambiguas... Você tera que escolher que tipo deve ser considerado o padrão... (Verificando qual ocorre mais vezes)

Comment: O problema ao guardar na base de dados tem por origem o já discutido nas respostas. Contudo, não devias acrescentar problemas na tua pergunta atual pois as respostas deixam de ser válidas, deverias abrir uma nova pergunta para lidar com o problema que respeita à base de dados.

Comment: @Zuul feito, obrigado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem várias formas de resolver isto dependendo da sua necessidade. Uma delas é esta:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '31/10/2014')));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uqhkmB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cfdmajsg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Date/Formated.php).

Em condições normais a função [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) aceita data no formato `Y-m-d`. Fazendo esta conversão para um formato europeu (com o traço no lugar da barra) ele aceita em `d-m-Y`.

Esta não é a melhor solução (pode haver ambiguidades) mas é uma que se aproxima do jeito que você está usando.

É bom dar uma lida nas outras respostas e no comentário na pergunta. Você pode ter problemas com o formato entrante desta forma a não ser que você possa garantir antes que está tudo correto, o que me parece pouco provável que isto esteja acontecendo. Você está resolvendo sue problema do momento mas pode causar outros no futuro se não garantir o formato.

Comment: obrigado!..........

Answer (score 9):

## PHP 5 >= 5.3.0

Podes fazer uso das funções de DateTime, particularmente  [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/10/2014');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');    // Output: 2014-10-31
```

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/KeH3XR).

---

## Em detalhe

Para clarificar, qualquer solução para o teu problema atual passa por fazer a conversão da data mas com indicação do formato em que a mesma se encontra. É impossível detetar se o formato de entrada é `MM/DD` ou `DD/MM`.

A exceção seria nos casos em que o valor é maior que 12 onde logicamente se trata de um dia dado só termos 12 meses. Mas mesmo assim, nada garante que não existiu um engano por parte do utilizador ao digitar o valor para o mês.

A solução em cima dá-te um meio de converter a data onde indicas o formato de entrada junto com a data, podendo depois gerar a saída da forma pretendida.

Para exemplificar conforme o teu caso:

```
// entrada com MÊS / DIA / ANO
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '11/12/2014');

echo $date1->format('Y-m-d');    // Output: 2014-11-12

// entrada com DIA / MÊS / ANO
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/10/2014');
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d');    // Output: 2014-10-31
```

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/XxFqUS).

Comment: obrigado pela força

Answer (score 3):

Ao que parece você tem um problema mais sério do que apenas formatação de datas: pois elas estão normalizadas ou padronizadas num único tipo/formato de entrada.

Como isso não cabe ao escopo do tópico, caso eu tenha assumido corretamente, a solução apresentada pelo Zuul, apesar de correta do ponto de vista programático, não é suficiente pois leva em conta um único formato de data.

Sendo assim, ofereço a função abaixo, criada por um amigo de fórum introduzida aqui na comunidade [noutro tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21841/250):

```
/**
 * Altera uma data para outro formato
 *
 * @param string $date String contendo a data a ser formatada
 * @param string $outputFormat Formato de saida
 * @throws Exception Quando não puder converter a data
 * @return string Data formatada
 * @author Hugo Ferreira da Silva
 */
function parseDate($date, $outputFormat = 'd/m/Y'){
    $formats = array(
        'd/m/Y',
        'd/m/Y H',
        'd/m/Y H:i',
        'd/m/Y H:i:s',
        'Y-m-d',
        'Y-m-d H',
        'Y-m-d H:i',
        'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    );

    foreach($formats as $format){
        $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        if($dateObj !== false){
            break;
        }
    }

    if($dateObj === false){
        throw new Exception('Invalid date:' . $date);
    }

    return $dateObj->format($outputFormat);
}
```

Para testar:

```
$testDates = array(
    '2012-10-30 00:00:00',
    '06/01/1986 14',
    '06/12/1983 14:30:10',
    '1984-01-06 14:30:10',
);

foreach($testDates as $date){
    var_dump( parseDate($date, 'Y-m-d') );
    //var_dump( DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date) instanceof DateTime );
}
```

Saída:

```
string '2012-10-30' (length=10)
string '1986-01-06' (length=10)
string '1983-12-06' (length=10)
string '1984-01-06' (length=10)
```

Apenas para ilustrar o porquê de a solução do amigo Zuul não ser suficiente experimente com esse mesmo array de datas aleatórias criar um objeto DateTime **sem** alterar o formato:

```
foreach($testDates as $date){
    var_dump( DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date) instanceof DateTime );
}
```

Todas as quatro iterações resultam em FALSE porque nenhuma delas está no formato **d/m/Y** ao passo que a função aqui apresentada leva em conta os oito principais formatos de data/hora.

Conforme exposto nos comentários desta resposta a função aqui apresentada faz com que 11/12/2014 retorne 2014-12-11 que apesar de válido programaticamente não computa com a lógica requerida.

Isso ocorre porque primariamente a função leva em conta datas no formato brasileiro DIA/MÊS/ANO e como o `foreach`é interrompido quando um formato cria um objeto DateTime com sucesso resulta num falso positivo.

A solução é bastante simples, basta reordenar o array **$formatos** da forma que melhor lhe convier.

Por exemplo:

```
$formats = array(
    'Y-m-d',
    'Y-m-d H',
    'Y-m-d H:i',
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    'd/m/Y',
    'd/m/Y H',
    'd/m/Y H:i',
    'd/m/Y H:i:s',

);
```

Já faz com que **11/12/2014** retorne **2014-12-11** e **30/10/2014** retorne **2014-10-30**.

Mais uma consideração:

Da mesma forma que você pode e deve reordenar o array de formatos como melhor achar você também pode incluir novos formatos específicos a sua necessidade.

Como a primeira de suas datas está num formato válido para uma data mas não considerado nos formatos disponíveis (m/d/Y), basta adicioná-lo ao array:

```
$formats = array(
    'm/d/Y',        // <---
    'Y-m-d',
    'Y-m-d H',
    'Y-m-d H:i',
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    'd/m/Y',
    'd/m/Y H',
    'd/m/Y H:i',
    'd/m/Y H:i:s',
);
```

Porém tenha em mente que tanto esta solução quando a proposta pelo Zuul **irão falhar** segundo a lógica que você espera pois suas datas não estão normalizadas.

Tanto quanto eu sei não existe uma forma de detectar automaticamente se um dado componente de uma data é um dia, um mês ou um ano.

Colocando o novo formato **m/d/Y** no início de **$formats** retornará aquilo que se espera para a primeira data. Mas para a segunda retornaria **2016-06-10**, o que imagino ser um problema da própria DateTime pois não existe o mês 30.

Comment: Bom dia @BrunoAugusto, essa função é muito boa, porém!   <br/> conforme exemplo acima de data ela retorna `11/12/2014 // 2014-12-11` apesar de ser uma data válida, mais o correto desta em questão seria `2014-11-12` <br/> e se eu add na 1ª linha dos formatos de data `m/d/Y` para que ele retorne o correto a outra data fica errada `31/10/2014 // 2016-07-10`

Comment: **Observação:** Apesar de ser uma boa resposta, dado ser a mesma que [esta outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21841/223), efetivamente o procedimento que deverias adotar seria fechar esta pergunta como duplicata e não duplicar a tua resposta!

Comment: Relativamente à tua resposta, a mesma não atende aos requisitos da pergunta, ver [exemplo no Ideone para comprovar](http://ideone.com/1OD1AV). A pergunta lida com o problema onde uma data vem como `MÊS / DIA / ANO` e a outra data vem como `ANO / MÊS / DIA`. A função que sugeres, na sua forma atual falha e converte os dados de forma incorreta. Essa tua função é pode ser boa na resposta de onde a extraíste, mas para este cenário não atende ao problema em questão. **Nota:** Não negativei a resposta, mas se não ajustares a mesma, dado estar incorreta na sua forma atual, serei forçado a fazê-lo :)

Comment: Não há necessidade de ajuste, apenas de complemento da resposta. Isso ocorre porque a função leva em consideração primariamente datas no formato brasileiro **d/m/Y**. Mas se você inverter os formatos da variável **$formats** colocando os **Y-m-d** antes o resultado muda e, **11/12/2014** passa a retornar **2014-12-11**

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Correto, sugiro então uma atualização ao teu código de exemplo porque na sua forma atual, dentro do `foreach()` não expressa bem a tua sugestão para utilizar essa função. Talvez dois exemplos, um para cada data na pergunta, cada um com formato de saída adequado ;)

Comment: Eu tava escrevendo, mas vocês dois escrevem mais rápido que eu >.<

Comment: Sim @BrunoAugusto, você leu meu 1º comentário? se eu inverte o formato da data a outra data fica incorreta.

Comment: Complementei de novo a resposta

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, obrigado pela força