# Erro na gravação de datas

Tags: php, mysqli

Seguindo na linha de [Validar diferentes formatos de data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40262/validar-diferentes-formatos-de-data)

A função abaixo supriu minhas necessidades:

```
function validateDate( $date ){
   $europeu = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(current(explode(' ', trim($date)))));
   $brazil = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', current(explode(' ', trim($date))))));
   return ( $europeu != '1970-01-01' ? $europeu : ( $brazil != '1970-01-01' ? $brazil : null));
}
```

#### Saida:

```
validateDate('11/12/2014'); // MÊS/DIA/ANO -> 2014-11-12 OK
validateDate('31/10/2014'); // DIA/MÊS/ANO -> 2014-10-31 OK
```

Agora me deparo com mais um problema, ao gravar no DB utilizando essa função algumas datas (não todas) ficam assim:

```
0000-00-00
4537-11-13
7963-11-13
2014-10-29
```

A estrutura está assim:

```
Nome       Tipo Colação Atributos   Nulo    Padrão                    Extra
base_dataos  date                  Não  Nenhum wrap (padrão: none)
```

Inserindo manualmente pelo **phpmyadmin** a data grava corretamente, segue query gerada

```
INSERT INTO `banco`.`tabela` (`base_id`, `base_posto`,   `base_numeroos`, `base_numerosr`, `base_modelo`, `base_garantia`, `base_codays`, `base_codphi`, `base_dataos`, `base_full`, `base_upload`, `base_user`) VALUES (NULL, 'EMPRESA TESTE', '99999999999', '88888888888', 'NTRX', 'Na garantia', '33333', 'ap1212', '2014-11-13', 'N', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Admin');
```

A query usada no PHP

```
// dados pego de um arquivo excel
$data_os = validateDate( $data[5] );

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `tablea` (`base_posto`, `base_numeroos`, `base_numerosr`, `base_modelo`, `base_garantia`, `base_codays`, `base_codphi`, `base_dataos`, `base_user`) 
    VALUES ('".$posto."','".$numero_os."','".$numero_sr."','".$modelo."','".$garantia."','".$codigo_posto_ays."','".$codigo_posto_phi."','".$data_os."', '".$userLogin."')") 
    or die ( $mysqli->error );
```

Comment: Já tentou inserir uma data manualmente?

Comment: Sim @KhaosDoctor, na opção **inserir** do phpmyadmin add uma nova linha e gravou certo.

Comment: Ele mostra a query SQL?

Comment: O formato [`date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html) recebe os valores como `YYYY-MM-DD` na forma de uma _string_. Estás a inserir tipo: `'2014-10-29'`, ou seja, com plicas ?

Comment: @Zuul não entendi, o que á de errado? deveria ser tipo `VARCHAR` a coluna **base_dataos**?

Comment: @KhaosDoctor, complementei minha pergunta com sua dúvida

Comment: Já vi pela edição da pergunta que estás a usar plicas para guardar a data na base de dados. Se fizeres `var_dump($data_os);` antes do objeto `$mysqli` qual o resultado que obténs?

Comment: @Zuul, fui checar se tava importanto os dados corretamente conforme você sugeriu o `var_dump` e achei o BO. estou utilizando a class [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) para importar dados de uma planilha e gravar no DB. vi que as datas no formato `11/12/2014 // MÊS/DIA/ANO` a célula carrega com a formato **Geral** retornando algo do tipo `41770.67140046296` dai as datas estão gravando errado. A questão agora é como importar a planinha no formato TEXT sem formato

Comment: @Hugo Você vai precisar achar as datas para poder converter em dias de novo. Talvez pegar os valores reais das células?

Comment: @KhaosDoctor, então.. abri um [POST](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40344/importar-planilha-com-formato-texto-utilizando-phpexcel) com essa dúvida

Answer (score 1):

O problema era na importação da planilha, usando [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) as datas no formato `MM/DD/YYYY` retornava um valor assim `41770.67140046296` a solução está na pergunta: [Importar planilha com formato texto utilizando PHPExcel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40344/importar-planilha-com-formato-texto-utilizando-phpexcel)

Answer (score 0):

Passei por um problema muito parecido com o seu. Pesquisando um pouco eu encontrei a seguinte solução, simples, que resolveu meu problema.

Eu precisava capturar uma data preenchida em um formulário no formato DD/MM/YYYY e transformá-la para o formato YYYY-MM-DD e inserir no banco. Ao inserir no banco, algumas davam problema. Então, para solucionar, eu capturei a data do formulário e corrigi com uma única linha:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$data_corrigida = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));
```

Comment: Obrigado por seu post @Abbominavell