# Importar planilha com formato texto utilizando PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Como importar um arquivo excel como as células no formato TEXT

código

```
$file_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

try {
    $FileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify( $file_tmp ); 
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( $FileType ); 
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly( true );
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( $file_tmp );   
}catch( Exception $e ){
    die( $e->getMessage() );
}

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$fimColuna = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
$numero_de_linhas = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
$numero_de_colunas = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString( $fimColuna );

for( $row = 0; $row <= $numero_de_linhas; $row++ ){
    $data = array();
    for( $col = 0; $col < $numero_de_colunas; $col++ ){     
        $data[] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
    }
}
```

Da forma que está as datas no formato `11/12/2014 //MÊS/DIA/ANO` ficam assim: `41984.69211805556`

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda.

Comment: Separe o texto que resolveu o problema e cria uma resposta com ele, não misture isso com a pergunta.

Comment: @perdeu, feito!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize:

```
echo PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue(), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Perfeito! @RogerioCoelho, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

As datas só vinham dessa forma `41984.69211805556` quando era `11/12/2014 // MÊS/DIA/ANO` se fosse `31/10/2014 // DIA/MÊS/ANO` vinha normal.

Então verifico se a variável tem o tamanho de uma data normal

```
function isDate( $date ){
     return strlen(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', current(explode(' ', trim($date))))) == 8 ?  true : false;
}
```

E acrescento uma função do PHPExcel que trata a data da planinha

```
date('d/m/Y', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP( $data ) ); // 41984.69211805556 -> 11/12/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

É porque quando recebe a data pelo `getValue()`, ele retorna um float.

Faca:

```
$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
```

A proposito qual a versao do PHPExcel esta utilizando?

Comment: obrigado pela atenção, minha versão é a **1.8.0**, vou testar aqui sua solução e informo em seguida

Comment: deu erro `Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Cell::getNumberFormat() in ..`

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isto:

```
$data = trim( $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $i)->getValue()); 
$data = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("01/01/1900 + $data_fatura days - 2 days"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava com este mesmo problema porém com as respostas dadas fiz alguns testes o qual resolveu meu problema, segue abaixo como exemplo caso ainda nao tenha resolvido.

```
$data=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($coluna, $linha)->getValue(); //como é retornado 41121
echo date('d/m/Y', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP( $data ) ); //como fica depois de formatado 30/07/2012
```