# conversão de datas com php

Tags: php

Galera Hoje eu uso uma forma muito simples para converter datas do BD (padrão americano) para o PT-BR.

O forma que utilizo e assim:

```
$data_BD = "2016-07-27";

// Cria nome das variaveis
$ano = substr($data_BD,0,-6);
$mes = substr($data_BD,5,-3);
$dia = substr($data_BD,8);


$data = "$dia/$mes/$ano";
```

Bom minha dúvida é, o PHP tem alguma função nativa para realizar esta formatação? Pois tenho que converter tanto as datas do BD para o usuário e as que o usuário informa em `input` para salvar no BD.

Comment: Acho que isso responde: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21774/91

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função `strtotime` e `date`:

```
$data_BD = "2016-07-27";
$data = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data_BD));

echo $data; // 27/07/2016
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/RSEhSw)

Se preferir usar [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$data_BD = "2016-07-27";

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data_BD);
$data = $dt->format('d/m/Y');

echo $data; // 27/07/2016
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/9KI3qW)