# Calcular diferença de dias entre duas datas [PHP]

Tags: php, data, get

Boa tarde a todos!
Fiz pesquisa antes de fazer a pergunta, mas não obtive resposta para a minha duvida em nenhuma delas.

Preciso de ajuda em fazer com que o seguinte código receba as duas datas pela variável $_GET, exemplo (.php?data1=23-09-16&data2=20-09-16).
Basicamente apresentar por extenso as datas inseridas e mostrar a diferença de dias entre as mesmas.

Fiz um exercicio funcional, qual a melhor forma de o adaptar para receber as datas do exterior?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>teste dias</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$br="<br>";

$agora=mktime(17,00,00,9,23,2016); 
$agora=date("F d, Y - g:i:s a", $agora);
echo "Hoje e agora são: ".$agora.$br;

$dia1=mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2016);
$dia2=mktime(0,0,0,2,1,2016);

echo (($dia2-$dia1)/60/60/24)." dias".$br;
echo $br;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Relacionada [Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/como-calcular-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-duas-datas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para o formato DD-MM-AA especificado na pergunta, precisamos separar os componentes da data para converter o ano para 4 dígitos:

```
$data1 = explode( '-', $_GET['data1'] );
$data2 = explode( '-', $_GET['data2'] );

echo $dia1 = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $data1[1], $data1[0], 2000+$data1[2] );
echo $dia2 = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $data2[1], $data2[0], 2000+$data2[2] );

echo ( $dia2 - $dia1 ) / 86400;
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/XVQ1gR)**.

Uma maneira mais simples, se você puder já enviar o valor com 4 dígitos no ano, é essa:

```
$dia1=strtotime( $_GET['data1'] );
$dia2=strtotime( $_GET['data2'] );

echo ( $dia2 - $dia1 ) / 86400;
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/yL2MVH)**.

A função `strtotime` faz a interpretação da *string* conforme o separador.

- Datas com `/` são consideradas como `MM/DD/AAAA`;
- Datas com `-` são consideradas como `DD-MM-AAAA`;

Se suas datas estiverem em formato MM/DD/AA, e você preferir usar outro critério de conversão, essa postagem pode ser útil:

> [Como inverter datas no php, independente do formato?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21774/70)

Comment: Muito Obrigado Bacco, toda a ajuda foi muito boa, mas foi a sua ajuda que acabei por utilizar! Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 4):

Use o método [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php) para transformar a data em um objeto [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php) a partir de um formato.

Em seguida, use o método `DateTime::diff` para computar a diferença entre datas.

```
$d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $_GET['data1'])
$d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $_GET['data2'])

$d2->diff($d1)->format('%a');
```

O método `diff` retornará uma instância do objeto [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php).

Veja aqui a tabela de  símbolos que podem ser usados para formatação da diferença entre datas (`DateInterval`).

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php