# Erro na função date do php?

Tags: php, html, funções, data

Tenho o seguinte problema, meu campo data no formulário está configurado conforme o código abaixo

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#txtVencimento").mask('00/00/0000');        
});
</script>
```

E recebo o mesmo na seguinte variável $vencimento e já uso a classe date() para converter e enviar para o banco de dados conforme o código abaixo

```
$vencimento =   date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['txtVencimento']));
```

por exemplo se digita a data 18/01/2017 no input a saída na variável $vencimento está sendo 1969-31-12, já usei esta função outras vezes desta forma e funcionou corretamente, mas agora estou com este erro, tem outra forma de trabalhar sem ser com replace?
o bando de dados é mysql na versão 5.6 e php na versão 5.6 a hospedagem é remota. Obrigado.

Comment: [Como inverter datas no php, independente do formato?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21774/91)

Comment: @rray foi a melhor alternativa, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
$vencimento =   date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST['txtVencimento']));
```