# fomatar data php

Tags: php, jquery-ui

Estou tentnado converter uma data que vem de um datapicker, a data vem no formato `dd/mm/yy`, mas para poder trabalhar com ela no mysql, preciso que ela esteja no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Estou usando o código a seguir:

```
    $ini = $_POST['inicio'];
    $newDateini = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime('$ini'));
    $newDatefim = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['fim']));
```

PS: eu poderia colocar o `dateformat` como `yy-mm-dd` no datapicker, mas isso tonaria a data confusa para o usuario.

Se eu selecionar a data de hoje, por exemplo, e solicitar um `echo $ini` o resultado será `28/05/2017`. Porém quando solicito um `echo $newDateini` ao invés de retornar a data em `2017-05-28`, me retorna como se a data estivesse vazia(`1970-01-01`)

Comment: certo... e qual é o problema?

Comment: @FReNeTiC, não notei que nao havia feito a pergunta pela metade,  desculpe. Editei a pergunta explicnado o problema

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21841/250 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/aGymWF)

```
$ini = "28/05/2017";
$ini =str_replace("/", "-", $ini);
$newDateini = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime("$ini"));

echo $newDateini;
```

> strtotime — Interpreta qualquer descrição de data/hora em texto em inglês em timestamp Unix
>
> A variável  `'$ini'` entre aspas simples não é processada, mude para aspas duplas   `"$ini"`

No PHP as aspas duplas (") e a aspas simples (') assim como outras linguagens também definem uma string, mas há diferenças entre elas. As strings formadas por aspas duplas são dinâmicas, ou seja o seu conteúdo é alterado conforme o valor de uma variável dentro do contexto, caso tenha uma variável é claro. Enquanto as aspas simples são estáticas e não fornecem mecanismos para a variação do seu conteúdo mesmo que tenha uma variável definida nela. Exemplos.

- $teste = 10;

  echo 'O numero da camisa do Pelé era $teste';

  saida:  `O numero da camisa do Pelé era $teste`
- $teste = 10;

  echo "O numero da camisa do Pelé era $teste";

  saida:  `O numero da camisa do Pelé era 10`

Conseguimos ver claramente a diferença entre as duas formas. Logo se houver dúvida de quando usar uma forma ou usar a outra forma tenha em mente que as aspas duplas é dinâmica e interpretativa enquanto as aspas simples são estáticas. Assim caso você queira incluir na sua string um valor variável ou um dos carácteres (\n,\r,\t,\r\n) utilize as aspas duplas, caso contrário use as aspas simples.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação Leo, ajudou muito!