# Formatar valor para data

Tags: php, data

Preciso formatar um valor para data... eu busco pelo link do valor seguinte:

> 20181107

No caso seria 07/11/2018, hoje. Preciso pegar esse valor e formatar no formato `2018-11-07`, tentei da seguinte forma:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('20181107'));
```

Porém, em alguns casos ele coloca o dia no lugar do mês, ai queria uma solução pra isso ou apenas um código que inserisse um hífen apos 4 dígitos e após 6 dígitos, seria mais simples também.

Comment: Pode dizer em que casos acontece de colocar o dia no lugar do mês? Não consegui reproduzir.

Comment: Talvez não se aplique ao seu caso (não queira usar por diversos motivos), mas se tiver de lidar com datas frequentemente, talvez valha a pena dar uma olhada na biblioteca [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). Inclusive ela é a lib padrão adotada pelo Laravel.

Comment: "Colocar o dia no lugar do mês"... Quem faz isso? O PHP ou o retorno da url?

Comment: Isso ? [Como inverter datas no PHP, independente do formato?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21774/91)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `createFromFormat` do objeto `DateTime`:

```
<?php
    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20181107')->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Desta forma você consegue definir o formato de entrada, e na função `format`, você define o formato de saída.

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/cJa2zj).

Você também pode ver mais sobre o `createFromFormat` [aqui](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 1):

Nicholas,

Você pode utilizar um substring comum para fazer isso, se seu caso é só formatação da string, segue abaixo:

```
substr("20181107",0,4)."-".substr("20181107",4,2)."-".substr("20181107",6,2)
```

Comment: Chegou a testar isso que me mandou?

Comment: @NicholasRuschelKrüger Você testou e não deu certo?

Comment: @NicholasRuschelKrüger coloquei o código em javascript, desculpa! kkkk
ajustei para php, abs!

Answer (score 1):

Já foi respondido, mas se você preferir a maneira procedural, pode fazer assim:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('Ymd', '20180120');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

As funções `date_create_from_format` e `date_format` correspondem a `DateTime::createFromFormat` e `DateTime::format`, respectivamente.